# Java - PGP Decryption Throwing 'Exception Starting Decryption'

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp, openpgp

I am facing an issue that is causing the PGPException: Exception starting decryption.

```
[main] INFO com.rxbenefits.service.impl.PGPEncryptionService - Got encrypted stream from input stream
[main] INFO com.rxbenefits.service.impl.PGPEncryptionService - Creating decryptor with provider: BC
[main] INFO com.rxbenefits.service.impl.PGPEncryptionService - Using private key with ID: 3d1dc62715cb3e82
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Exception starting decryption
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData.getDataStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.rxbenefits.service.impl.PGPEncryptionService.decryptFile(PGPEncryptionService.java:142)
    at com.rxbenefits.service.impl.PGPEncryptionServiceTest.testDecryptFile(PGPEncryptionServiceTest.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: premature end of stream in PartialInputStream
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream$PartialInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:205)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:121)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:197)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedData$TruncatedStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 30 more
```

The code is saying I am throwing the error at the `InputStream clearStream = publicKeyEncryptedData.getDataStream(new JcePublicKeyDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder() .setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()) .build(privateKey));` line within the decryption method below. I have a feeling that it might have something to do with the `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());` line at the top of my decryption method....but I am not sure.

This is my first time working with encryption, so would like any guidance if possible.

```
public static void decryptFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out, InputStream keyIn, char[] passwd) throws IOException, PGPException {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        try (InputStream encryptedStream = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in)) {
            log.info("Got encrypted stream from input stream");

            PGPObjectFactory pgpFactory = new PGPObjectFactory(encryptedStream, new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());
            PGPEncryptedDataList encryptedDataList = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpFactory.nextObject();

            if (encryptedDataList == null) {
                log.info("No encrypted data found in input stream");
                throw new PGPException("No encrypted data found in input stream");
            }

            // find the secret key needed to decrypt the message
            PGPSecretKeyRingCollection secretKeyRingCollection = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn), new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());
            PGPPrivateKey privateKey = null;
            PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData publicKeyEncryptedData = null;
            for (Object encryptedData : encryptedDataList) {
                if (encryptedData instanceof PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) {
                    publicKeyEncryptedData = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) encryptedData;
                    PGPSecretKey secretKey = secretKeyRingCollection.getSecretKey(publicKeyEncryptedData.getKeyID());
                    if (secretKey != null) {
                        privateKey = secretKey.extractPrivateKey(new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(passwd));
                        break;
                    } else {
                        log.info("No secret key found for message");
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No secret key found for message");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (privateKey == null) {
                log.info("No private key found for message");
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No private key found for message");
            }
            log.info("Creating decryptor with provider: " + Security.getProvider("BC").getName());
            log.info("Using private key with ID: " + Long.toHexString(publicKeyEncryptedData.getKeyID()));
            // create the decryptor and decrypt the message
            InputStream clearStream = publicKeyEncryptedData.getDataStream(new JcePublicKeyDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder()
                    .setProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
                    .build(privateKey));
            log.info("Created decryptor and decrypted message");

            PGPObjectFactory plainFactory = new PGPObjectFactory(clearStream, new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());
            Object message = plainFactory.nextObject();

            // handle the decrypted message
            if (message instanceof PGPCompressedData) {
                PGPCompressedData compressedData = (PGPCompressedData) message;
                InputStream compressedStream = new BufferedInputStream(compressedData.getDataStream());
                message = new PGPObjectFactory(compressedStream, new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator()).nextObject();
            }

            if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
                PGPLiteralData literalData = (PGPLiteralData) message;
                try (InputStream literalStream = literalData.getInputStream()) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = literalStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                log.info("Decrypted message of type PGPLiteralData");
            } else {
                log.info("Unknown message type: " + message.getClass().getName());
                throw new PGPException("Unknown message type: " + message.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to decrypt an encrypted file. I encrypted the file using a pub key provided to me by work and am decrypting by using the sec key and password provided by them as well.

It seems to be failing when trying to actually decrypt.
Knowing the pub and sec key are correct, along with the password, I am wondering if I might not be encrypting the file correctly? Could this be a possibility? When I open the encrypted file it looks very encrypted.

Pho

Comment: **[That exception should have a caused-by block in its stacktrace.](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData.java#L218)** Please include it if available; it's highly relevant.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you. I have updated my post to include the stacktrace.

Comment: Okay, premature EOF pretty strongly suggests the message is wrongly formatted/encoded, or damaged. How are you doing the encryption? Do you have or can you get GnuPG? If so, look at `gpg --list-packets $file`.

Comment: If your implementation produced the encrypted message, then it is very likely that you forgot to close the OutputStream obtained from the PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.